# Revert a committed transaction with Knex.js

Tags: javascript, transactions, knex.js

Is it possible to revert an already committed transaction just like this:

```
const trx = await transaction.start(Model.knex());

try {
  await doStuff(trx);
  await doOtherStuff(trx); // If this fails rollback is working well
  await trx.commit();
  await externalAPICall(); // External API call failed! Error!
} catch (err) {
  await trx.rollback(err); // Can I rollback if externalAPICall throwed and error? (Commit is already done)
}
```

Comment: That's not really how transactions work. Transactions are atomic units of work that can be committed, or rolled back exactly once. If you could commit repeatedly in a transaction, it wouldn't be atomic, as it would have already persisted results to the database. What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: `doStuff()` creates the data of a new user.
`externalAPICall()` is an external call to send an email to the user to finish the activation of the account.
Then if the activation user email fails I want to revert the new created user at database.

Comment: Then put `externalAPICall()` *before* `trx.commit()`. If it fails, `trx.commit()` won't be called so no data would be persisted.

Comment: @NikKyriakides Oops, I forgot to mention that `externalAPICall()` reads the email  inserted in `doStuff` so that option is not possible I think

Comment: Are you talking about the user actually clicking the activation email and activating his account? If that's the case you should be aware that this is not how account activation mechanics work. You create the user in your database with a flag `activatedAccount: false` and send the activation email. When (and if) the user clicks the activation email you go and toggle that flag to `true`.

Comment: @NikKyriakides Yes thats exactly how it works. The service to send activation is just in other server. But the flow is similar.

Comment: Ok, you need to create the user **without** waiting for activation. When the user activates the account via email the other server should notify you and you should toggle the flag for that user.

Comment: Not exactly, a bit difficult to explain. I create a user without activation. Then I request the other server to send the activation email (throws error if the email is not found at same database, so I need to commit the transaction). If this request fails, I would like to revert the inserted user. But seems not possible using transactions.

Comment: Doesn't the activation-email server respond immediately whether the activation mail was successfully sent or not? If not then you can't use transactions; instead you might need to use a pattern called [Distributed Saga](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html) or [2PC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol), both approaches being a bit complex to implement. That being said I think `externalAPICall()` should fail if the activation email can't be sent. We use [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/) and it replies in the same request whether the email was sent or not.

Comment: Thanks for the links, look really interesting. Ill check them. Yes, `externalAPICall()` responds inmediately. But since `externalAPICall()` checks the email of the already comitted user data on the same database, theres no way to revert it. I just wanted to make sure every single step is successfull on my 'create user' operation.

Comment: Ok, so why does `externalAPICall()` try to read the email off the database? Don't you already have the user's email available in the request parameters when you try to perform all these steps you have in your question?

Comment: So, what you seem to want is a distributed transaction (essentially a transaction that encompasses the action of multiple services). That's tricky to implement, and probably not worth it here. It's going to be a lot easier to just delete the user if externalAPICall fails.

Comment: @NikKyriakides Yes that would be actually a solution. Ill keep on mind for the future. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @NickBailey I see... Yes I thought about a delete user operaion but I thought there might be some kind of `reset --hard {commit}` for Knex, but I see there isnt haha Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
await knex.transaction(async (trx) => {
  await doStuff(trx);
  await doOtherStuff(trx);
  await externalAPICall();
}
```

in this syntax commit() and rollback() is implicit :)

Comment: The problem is that I needed to revert the transaction if `externalAPICall` failed. The problem is that `externalAPICall` reads the data of `doOtherStuff` and `doStuff`. So its just not possible so both should be already commited :)

Comment: ohhh I think it would work if you can make sure that knex uses the same connection in the middle of the transaction. use trx.select() instead of knex.select(). You can read the modified data from the connection that the transaction was made in, you don't need to commit it

Comment: oh now I see externalAPICall doesn't use the same connection/session. then I think it's not possible....